# How to connect a ball (provided interface) and a socket (required interface) which are far from each other in a composite structure?

Tags: uml

Consider a composite structure with two instances of components :C1 and :C2.
:C1 requires the interface I2 provided by :C2.

The common option is to make a ball-socket connection.

However, my diagram is quite large, :C1 and :C2 are far from each other and I want to have my ball and my socket beside the corresponding instance of component.

If it was a component diagram (C1,C2 instead of :C1,:C2), it would be a dependency relationship. What in the case of a composite structure ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way using Connectors.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Composite structure is already kind of mix between a classifier and instance level diagram, so I don't think there is something like that.

If you define your parts as instances of components, you can maybe draw a component diagram to show this dependeny (like you said). It sound like a good strategy - static dependencies on a component diagram(s) and the corresponding run-time instance structure on composite structure.

Regarding the fact that your composite structure is too large - you should never have this kind of problem with UML. YOu should just try to break your structure into several levels, diagrams, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In U.M.L., You don't have to show all the whole structure of classes, or interfaces, just the ones you need. It's common to show a whole representation of a class or an interface in one diagram, and, to show a partial view in other diagrams, specially when it's related to associations.

Yo can also use packages, conceptually, and use package notation at the identifiers.

[1] First Diagram that displays a lot of detail, with only interface declaration.

```
...........................................................
...........................................................
..+-------------------------------------+..................
..|           <<Interface>>             |..................
..|        A::B::C::StreamInterface     |..................
..+-------------------------------------+..................
..| [+]  bool CanRead()                 |..................
..| [+]  bool CanWrite()                |..................
..| [+]  bool CanSeek()                 |..................
..+---+---------------------------------+..................
......|....................................................
......|....................................................
......|...........+-------------------------------------+..
......|........+--+            <<Interface>>            |..
......|........|..|     X::Y::Z::ReadStreamInterface    |..
......|........|..+-------------------------------------+..
......|........|..| [+]  bool CanRead()                 |..
......|........|..| [+]  bool CanWrite()                |..
......|..../|..|..| [+]  bool CanSeek()                 |..
......|.../.|..|..| [+]  bool IsEoS(...)                |..
......+--<..|--+..| [+]  bool Read(...)                 |..
..........\.|..|..+-------------------------------------+..
...........\|..|...........................................
...............|...........................................
...............|..+-------------------------------------+..
...............+--+            <<Interface>>            |..
..................|    M::N::O::WriteStreamInterface    |..
..................+-------------------------------------+..
..................| [+]  bool CanRead()                 |..
..................| [+]  bool CanWrite()                |..
..................| [+]  bool CanSeek()                 |..
..................| [+]  bool Write(...)                |..
..................+-------------------------------------+..
...........................................................
...........................................................
```

[2] Another Diagram that displays a lot of detail,
with class declarations that support interfaces.

```
..........................................................................................
..........................................................................................
..+-------------------------------------+..../|..+-------------------------------------+..
..|            <<Interface>>            |.../.|..|              <<Class>>              |..
..|     X::Y::Z::ReadStreamInterface    +--<..+--+       Q::R::S::ReadStreamClass      |..
..+-------------------------------------+...\.|..+-------------------------------------+..
..| [+]  bool CanRead()                 |....\|..| [+]  bool CanRead()     <<virtual>> |..
..| [+]  bool CanWrite()                |........| [+]  bool CanWrite()    <<virtual>> |..
..| [+]  bool CanSeek()                 |........| [+]  bool CanSeek()     <<virtual>> |..
..+-------------------------------------+........| [+]  bool IsEoS(...)    <<virtual>> |..
.................................................| [+]  bool Read(...)     <<virtual>> |..
.................................................+-------------------------------------+..
..........................................................................................
..........................................................................................
..+-------------------------------------+..../|..+-------------------------------------+..
..|            <<Interface>>            |.../.|..|              <<Class>>              |..
..|     M::N::O::WriteStreamInterface   +--<..+--+       D::E::F::WriteStreamClass     |..
..+-------------------------------------+...\.|..+-------------------------------------+..
..| [+]  bool CanRead()                 |....\|..| [+]  bool CanRead()     <<virtual>> |..
..| [+]  bool CanWrite()                |........| [+]  bool CanWrite()    <<virtual>> |..
..| [+]  bool CanSeek()                 |........| [+]  bool CanSeek()     <<virtual>> |..
..+-------------------------------------+........| [+]  bool Write(...)    <<virtual>> |..
.................................................+-------------------------------------+..
..........................................................................................
..........................................................................................
..........................................................................................
```

Cheers.